# Spouse visa after Brexit needed?

Tags: visas, schengen

I am a German settled in the UK with a wife from the Philippines who is settled as well. Will she need a visa if we want to travel to Germany to visit my mother? We did not need one before but has that changed after Brexit?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are the general rules, and then there are special COVID restrictions still in force. *Generally,* the Philippines are not on Annex II, so your wife will need a visa. This should be granted by examining her marriage certificate only, rather than the usual financial requirements, ties to the homeland, etc.

Here is what the [Innenministerium](https://www.bmi.bund.de/SharedDocs/faqs/DE/themen/bevoelkerungsschutz/coronavirus/reisebeschraenkungen-grenzkontrollen/IV-reisebeschraenkungen-im-aussereuropaeischen-luft-und-seeverkehr-einreisen-aus-drittstaat/welche-besonderheiten-gelten-fuer-die-einreise-von-familienangehoerigen-aus-drittstaaten.html) says.

Comment: Isn't visum an indefinite *plural*? I would assume the wife would only need one...

Comment: @CGCampbell, it is the German term, coming back from the German site I had double-checked.

Comment: As the spouse of a German national who resides outside the EU, freedom of movement would not apply for a German visa application, so financial requirements and ties to the place of residence should be considered.  I don't see anything making an exception for family of Germans with settled status under the EU Settlement Scheme (and "settled in the UK" doesn't necessarily imply that the asker of the question is settled under that scheme).

Comment: @phoog, "Ehegatten bzw. eingetragene Lebenspartner von Deutschen, EU-Bürgern oder Staatsangehörigen Islands, Liechtensteins, Norwegens oder der Schweiz können unabhängig davon einreisen, ob die Bezugsperson ihren dauerhaften Aufenthalt in Deutschland oder im Ausland hat."

Comment: There's an English language version of that page, which is probably more appropriate for this English-language site, but regardless, it concerns COVID-19 requirements, not visa requirements ("Welche Besonderheiten gelten ...?").  The public health restrictions are relaxed for family members who benefit from free movement and for some categories of those who don't, including family of German citizens and "Drittstaatsangehörige Familienangehörige der sog. "Kernfamilie" ... von Drittstaatsangehörigen mit einem bestehenden Aufenthaltsrecht in Deutschland."